Login screen appears two times
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
When I try to login after boot, I enter the password it seems to be login but it returns me to the login screen, I enter the password again it finally log me in.
this happens on every login so it's not that I may have entered a wrong password.
Thanks for Help

This question is similar to: Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Given your description, I'd also check whatever changes you've made, as you may have setup something to occur on login that takes longer than is available causing the first login to fail (ie. whatever you setup needs to include a delay, OR be done differently) so its not interfering with a login process. If this (what I'm thinking of) is the issue; I'd expect problems only on first attempt after a reboot; and not if you logout & login again.. but you've provided few specifics as to your actual install  (thus we're limited mostly to guesses)
